# What were the most significant events in the EE community (from 2014-2015)?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange post: [What were the most significant events in EE community from (2014-2015)?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/525466/what-were-the-most-significant-events-in-ee-community-from-2014-2015)

Hello, my name is Ane and I'm a business student working on a uni project about online communities. I'm looking for an answer to my question:

What were the most significant events in the EE community from (2014-2015)?

As I didn't know I wasn't supposed to ask this question at electronics.stackexchange.com, I hope I'll get some answers here (I'm new to this community, so sorry if I'm on the wrong site). I would be really greatful to anyone (moderators, members, etc.) who could help me. It could be anything, e.g. badges, personnel or ownership changes, some technical issues or changes, introduction of major products relevant to the community etc.

Thanks a lot!

Best regards, Ane

Comment: It's also definitely off-topic _here_. Find a discussion forum if you want someone to talk to.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to track the EE community would be to look at the meta itself ( https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/) and read all of questions and answers. I don't think you have access to the chat,  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering
but if you can look (don't know if it's possible) back on anything in that time frame that would be good. Other than that I can't think of anything especially significant during that time period other than many questions being answered and asked.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and advice! I'll see what I can find there, going back to the questions and answers in the community seems to be possible, but in the chat I'll have to manually scroll all the way back (it's worth doing it though, so thanks!). Edit: I found the transcript option and there I can go to that specific time frame!